# android windowMinWidthMinor don't work on small screen

Tags: android, user-interface

style:

```
<style name="DialogTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">80%</item>
</style>
```

java:

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this, R.style.DialogTheme);
dialog.setTitle("title");
dialog.show();
```

This works fine until I test it on a small screen device(480 * 800)

I want to know why?